# It's time to talk about [date] and [date-time]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[date](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/date) and [date-time](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/date-time) are both undefined meta tags that are used in a variety of ways related to dates (and times).  Even though these are meta tags, there might be some value in categorizing the subject area.

On the other hand, these are specific functions in a number of applications and answers are not generally applicable from one to another.  If it is useful to have dedicated tags for these functions, it may be appropriate to make them application-specific (which would require new tags and contribute to tag bloat).

I'll just put this out there for the community to decide the appropriate course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I found this. [date](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/date) has a description. [date-time](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/date-time) has a synonym, but no description.

I have no idea what [date-time](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/date-time) is!

#### It seems to me that *date-time* should be converted to *date* or at least converted to a synonym of *date*. I can't for the life of me figure out what distinction there possibly could be.

Someone call trogdor.

Comment: A blast from the past.  My recollection is that "date" is pretty unambiguous.  Time is used in at least three kinds of ways: time of day (wall clock, on-screen clock, CMOS clock), triggering intervals (like CPU clock), and timing intervals relative to a process (segment or location in a multi-media file, duration of a transition in a presentation, etc.).  Time is a free-for-all.  I thought there might be some value in more-refined time tags.  [date-time] clearly refers to wall-clock time, as opposed to the other kinds of time.  But also, how to keep usage clean?